# using a loop through matrices stored in a list

Tags: r, list, loops

I would like to run a function within a loop, where the input data comes from a list with consecutive numbers, as in the following way:

```
output <-create_list(input) %% function that creates the list
```

output has M1,N1,M2,N2,M3,N3,M4 and N4

```
for (i in 1:4) {

  m <- output$M[i] %% This is wrong but is a good way to show my aim
  n <- output$N[i]  
  output2<- fiting(m,n) %% target function 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
# You want to keep the fits you generate, a list can hold everything
fits <- list()

# This generates a sequence that increments be two:
# i.e: 1, 3, 5, 7 etc, it won't generate any value greater
# than the maximum value (defined by length(output))
for(i in seq(1, length(output), by = 2))

  # Then just run the fitting function on each two values
  fits <- c(fits, fitting(output[[i]], output[[i + 1]]))

# Fits then contains a list of outputs
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Edited to make changes